# Communication between bluetooth and android app

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is my code for communication between bluetooth and android app. The app is supposed to obtain the obtain the UUID and bluetooth address.It will throw exception if the bluetooth address and UUID is invalid.The app shows an error saying UUID is invalid when I tried to debug it. I am not sure how to fix it.

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.UUID;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.iastate.nachoparty.rcpiapp.R;

    public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

        protected static final String label = "bluetooth1";
        Button buttonOn, buttonOff;
        protected static BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
        protected static BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        protected static OutputStream outstream = null;
        // SPP UUID service

        private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        //MAC address of bluetooth
        protected static String address = "00:02:72:cd:9f:60 ";//to be updated

        /* Called when the activity is first created */
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);
            buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_go);
            buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            //checkBTState();

            /*
            buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                       sendData("1");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     sendData("0");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            */
        }

        private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
                try {
                    final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord");
          //          return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(label, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection", e);

                }
            }
            //return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            return null;
        }

        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Log.d(label, "....onResume-try connect.....");
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            try {
                bluetoothSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error","In onResume() and socket create failed:"+e1.getMessage());
            }
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(label, "...Connecting.....");


            try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                Log.d(label, "...Connection ok...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                   errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
                }

            }
            Log.d(label, "...Create Socket...");

            try {
                outstream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            Log.d(label, "...In onPause()...");

            if (outstream != null) {
                try {
                    outstream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
                }
            }

            try     {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
               errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }
        private void checkBTState() {
            // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
            // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
            if(bluetoothAdapter==null) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
            } else {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Log.d(label, "...Bluetooth ON...");
                } else {
                    //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        protected void errorExit(String title, String message){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        protected void sendData(String message) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

            Log.d(label, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

            try {
                outstream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
                    msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
                //msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

                errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
            }
        }

    }
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.UUID;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.iastate.nachoparty.rcpiapp.R;

    public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

        protected static final String label = "bluetooth1";
        Button buttonOn, buttonOff;
        protected static BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
        protected static BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        protected static OutputStream outstream = null;
        // SPP UUID service

        //private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        //MAC address of bluetooth
        protected static String address = "00:02:72:cd:9f:60 ";//to be updated

        /* Called when the activity is first created */
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);
            buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_go);
            buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            //checkBTState();

            /*
            buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                       sendData("1");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     sendData("0");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            */
        }

        private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
                try {
                    final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord");
          //          return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(label, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection", e);

                }
            }
            //return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            return null;
        }

        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Log.d(label, "....onResume-try connect.....");
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            try {
                bluetoothSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error","In onResume() and socket create failed:"+e1.getMessage());
            }
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(label, "...Connecting.....");


            try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                Log.d(label, "...Connection ok...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                   errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
                }

            }
            Log.d(label, "...Create Socket...");

            try {
                outstream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            Log.d(label, "...In onPause()...");

            if (outstream != null) {
                try {
                    outstream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
                }
            }

            try     {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
               errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }
        private void checkBTState() {
            // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
            // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
            if(bluetoothAdapter==null) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
            } else {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Log.d(label, "...Bluetooth ON...");
                } else {
                    //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        protected void errorExit(String title, String message){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        protected void sendData(String message) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

            Log.d(label, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

            try {
                outstream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
                    msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
                //msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

                errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
            }
        }
```